# Intermittent dropped requests between Android and Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, urlconnection

Anyone using Java URLConnections to send GET requests from your Android app to a Python script hosted on Google App Engine?  I'm seeing rare user reports of IOExceptions and the corresponding requests are going unlogged in GAE.  I suppose this means their network connection dropped but I'm wondering if anyone has experience here.

Understand GAE has some spool up time but I thought the request would at least get logged before the latency causes problems.  I get the feeling I might be missing something here...

EDIT: I wrote a pretty vague question so I apologize.  I now believe my issue doesn't has anything to do with GAE in particular.  My question is: when using URLConnection in an Android app, is it best practice to check for a network connection before sending the request, catch IOExceptions and re-fire the request a certain number of times, or something else?

Cheers, Ryan

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that if it does not appear in the log, most probably it does not get to GAE at all.

I do see half-way connections getting dropped on GAE (Java), but with these - connection is first made, and then dropped by Android.

Comment: I agree these requests are almost certainly not getting to GAE.  Is it best practice to check for a network connection before firing a URLConnection?  Or perhaps I should catch the IOException and try again a certain number of times.

Comment: @Ryan it depends on your scenario. If you want to absolutely make sure that your connection goes through, you might want to try it using a call to a background service that retries until succeeds. Such a service can live even when your application is not "Running", and make sure that eventually the connection is made.